# Indirectly changing class parameters

Tags: c#

I'm displaying a class on a TreeListView (by [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)) using reflection. 
TreeListView works with a `ChildrenGetter()` delegate which gets the nodes to display (see [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-use-a-treelistview)).

In order to display the class (we'll call it the *reflected class*), the root of the tree is an instance of the class, and the `ChildrenGetter(object x)` uses reflection to return the **instances** of each child of the reflected class.

For example, for this class:

```
public class Folder
{
    public int BuildNumber { get; set; }
    public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

The root will be a instance of Folder, and it will have 2 children nodes, containing the value of BuildNumber and MaxSpeed.

This works okay, but only for display. I'd like to be able to change the values of BuildNumber and MaxSpeed on the UI so that they would actually change on the instance of the reflected class held by the tree root.

So there are two ways of doing this:

1. Save the parent (owning class) of each node in the tree node, and creating an "address path" for each node, then using reflection find the changed node and actually change it (in the reflected class instance)
2. Instead of the nodes of the tree containing the values of the reflected class parameters, they could hold some kind of a pointer to the parameters in the reflected class instance.

Is solution 2 even possible? Is there some pointer equivalent in C# that could allow such functionality?

Can you think of a better solution?

Notes:

- The tree can have classes containing other classes, and depth isn't limited. For now, I'm not using structs anywhere
- I can't change the reflected class. It is autogenerated
- Safe code is preferred, but if nothing else is available unsafe code will do

Comment: Can you attach a `Action<T>` to it so you can execute that as setter for that property?

Comment: Yes, but how will the action know which parameter to change?

Comment: If you can, attach an action `val => instance.X = val` to a tag or something.

Comment: That's the best solution I could hope for. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I added it as an answer, please let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to attach some metadata to the controls / tree items you create, you could create an `Action<T>` and assign it to the tag or something like that.

If you have its instance, you could so something like this (used `string` as sample data type):

```
Action<string> action = val => instance.X = val;
```